# Activity initialization

Tags: android

How to make sure `Activity` window get initialized only once in Android application. I was asked this question once and I am not sure what the answer is.
 But it seems like we can do it in `onCreate()` method.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Initialized here once
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the right way of doing it or is there any other way we can achieve this?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are looking to do.  The snippet you posted will work such that the code inside your `if` statement will only be called when the Activity is initialized for the first time, and not on any subsequent calls to onCreate() (such as due to a configuration change like device rotation).  If that's not what you are needing, please clarify further.  Cheers.

Comment: I want to initialize some member variable in this `if` block and want to make sure that these should get called only once. Is there any other scenario in which this `if` block will get executed except very first time. 
 I guess similar kind of work can be done using android:launchMode flags.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `singleTop` for the [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for the `Activity`.